# Javascript Audio Html

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, audio

I'm trying to make an audio player with html and javascript. Every time someone clicks play, it plays the audio files that are selected in the check boxes: https://gyazo.com/9c93954e89dcd975ed47956b8563b177

HTML Audio

```
 <audio id="player">

 </audio>
```

HTML checkboxes

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
        <h5 class="mb-0"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo" class="">Collapsible
                Test1</a></h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="card-body collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionexample" style="">
    
            <div class="title-choice">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="1.mp3" id="playable_file">
                <label for="">1.mp3</label>
            </div>

        
            <div class="title-choice">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="2.mp3" id="playable_file">
                <label for="">2.mp3</label>
            </div>

         
    </div>
    </div>
```

play_files.js

```
var i;
var ii;

var checked;

function save_files() {

    i = 0;
    ii = 0;

    checked = []; 

    $("input[id='playable_file']:checked").each(function ()
    {
        checked.push($(this).attr("name"));
    });  

    addNumber (); 
    play_files ();
    setInterval(function() {check(); }, 3000);

}

function addNumber () {
    if(i != 0) { 
        document.getElementById("audio" + i - 1).remove();
    }
    var container = document.createElement('source');
    container.src = "./audiofiles/" + checked[i]; 
    container.id = "audio" + i;
    container.type = "audio/mpeg";

    $('#player').append(container);

    i++
}

function check () {

    if(ii != 0) {
        document.getElementById("player").onended = function(){
            play_files();
        };
    }
    
}

function play_files() {

    document.getElementById("player").play();

}
```

The thing is on chrome, but the sound doesn't work at all. On Firefox, it plays the first selected audio file, but then just full on errors.

error: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).ended is not a function.

and

warning: Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats: audio / mpeg.

So to sum it up -> I get errors on the second file. I can't play the sounds in chrome, And I don't really know how to start the next file after a certain time after the first audio file stops.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.Ended();`, you can use `.onended` and set it to a function with what you want it to run.

Other audio types are `audio/mpeg3`, `audio/x-mpeg`, and `audio/x-mpeg-3`. See if any of those work.

Example of onended:

```js
document.getElementById("sound").onended = function(){
    alert("The sound ended.")
};
```

Comment: So I tried what you said but all those formats aren't supported for some reason. I also updated my js file with your solution which kinda works. I just can't get the next song to play!

Comment: I don't know if it's an issue with the browser, can you try reinstalling firefox?